# Is there a sub-quadratic method of calculating the expanded polynomial from its roots?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

If I have the roots of a polynomial, $r_1, r_2,\ldots, r_n$ is there a fast way (hopefully sub-quadratic) to find the expanded polynomial (or equivalently its coefficients)?

I know of Vieta's formula and using dynamic programming it seems as though you can do this in polynomial-time, but I am hoping for within log-factors of linear.

Thanks in advance,
Pat

Comment: supposing the polynomial is monic and you don't care about floating point errors, you should be able to do this in the neighborhood of $n\cdot \log(n)$ by using the Fast Fourier Transform.  A naive application of Discrete Fourier Transform is quadratic but there are numerous overlapping subproblems with n+1 th roots of unity which basically results in the FFT.

Answer (score 0):

If the roots of $f(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + c_0$ are $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$, then:
$$
f(x) = c_n(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n) \tag{*}
$$
If you only have the $r_i$, then you can't determine $c_n$. If you know $c_n$, then formal multiplication of the product $(*)$ will be much better than using Vieta's formulas. I don't see how dynamic programming is of any use here.